# Python Output Error

Tags: python, curl, popen

I am making a simple script using python to check if an IP is on a vpn or not using the hostname, however I am using a vpn to test on and I used my real IP both in which the result reads "vpn not in use" even when it is and the output ("From the curl command) reads so.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen,PIPE
import socket
import time
import optparse
parser = optparse.OptionParser()
parser.add_option("-t", "--hst", action="store", dest="host", help="Target host to check if is using VPN", default=False)
options, args = parser.parse_args()
host = socket.gethostbyname(options.host)
def hostname_check(hst):
        check = subprocess.Popen(['curl ipinfo.io/'+hst], shell=True)
        if('No Hostname' in str(check)):
                print("Host: %s - Virtual Private Network in use") % host

        elif('No Hostname' not in str(check)):
                print("Host: %s - Virtual Private Network NOT in use") % host
hostname_check(options.host)
```

The command to execute: ./vpnchecker.py --hst 162.224.81.174
The Output:

```
    Host: 162.244.81.174 - Virtual Private Network NOT in use
user@LAPTOP:~$ {
  "ip": "162.244.81.174",
  "hostname": "No Hostname",
  "city": "",
  "region": "",
  "country": "RO",
  "loc": "46.0000,25.0000",
  "org": "AS19624 Data Room, Inc"
}
```

It should read: Host: 162.244.81.174 - Virtual Private Network in use and I do not want the output from the curl command to be displayed on the screen.

Comment: Is it just me or are you missing a bunch of punctuations (quotations, brackets, commas) from `parser.add_option` and onwards.

Comment: @abccd No, the parser is fine, I have written it in many programs.

Comment: I mean the code you posted here, try running this. Perhaps you copy and pasted wrong

Comment: Yes, definitely closing " missing in the `parser.add_option` line, and possibly some other stuff in the original code above.

Comment: @abccd, Yes, sorry, when I copied and pasted, the closing of my parser.add_option was cut off, unfortunately that is not the error, I will fix it now, then try running on your pc's tell me if you are experiencing this same problem, I have been trying to fix it all day...starting to make me what to do malevolent things to my PC hah.

Comment: @Levon, Yes, sorry, when I copied and pasted, the closing of my parser.add_option was cut off, unfortunately that is not the error, I will fix it now, then try running on your pc's tell me if you are experiencing this same problem, I have been trying to fix it all day...starting to make me what to do malevolent things to my PC hah.

Comment: Your call to Popen doesn't specify a `stdout` or `stderr` argument. The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) says `With the default settings of None, no redirection will occur; the child’s file handles will be inherited from the parent. `

Comment: An alternative way to download web content, without using Popen, can be found at [simple web content download with urllib](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/1792/web-scraping-with-python/19297/simple-web-content-download-with-urllib-request#t=201704041415565322194), part of the stackoverflow python documentation project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a different method using requests, therefore instead of using curl to pull web data, I got the same data from the requests lib. Here is the code for anyone intrested:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen,PIPE
import socket
import time
import requests
import optparse
parser = optparse.OptionParser()
parser.add_option("-t", "--hst", action="store", dest="host", help="Target host to check if is using VPN", default=False)
from requests import *
options, args = parser.parse_args()
host = socket.gethostbyname(options.host)
def hostname_check(hst):
        check = requests.get('http://ipinfo.io/'+hst).text
        if('No Hostname' in check):
                print("Host: %s - Virtual Private Network in use") % host

        elif('No Hostname' not in check):
                print("Host: %s - Virtual Private Network NOT in use") % host
hostname_check(options.host)
```